# How to Moq a service in a controller which use unitofwork with generic repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tdd, moq, unit-of-work

I am a newbie in TDD (Asp.net MVC3 environment) and trying to adopt TDD as our better better development approach.

In our production code,we have a following scenario

### In web

```
//Autofac used to resolve Dependency
TestController(XService xSerivice,YSerivice yService) 
{_xService =xService,_YService= yService}

[HTTPPost]
ActionResult Create(A1 a1)
{
  _xService.XUnitOfWork.A1.add(a1)
  _xService.XUnitOfwork.SaveChanges();

}
```

// where X, Y are different context,Concrete class, no interface implemented!

### In Business Layer

`Xservice(XUnitofWork)`   // no interface implemented!

**In DAL Layer**

```
'XUnitofWork:DataRepostory(Generic)...
    {
      GenericRepository<a1Entity> A1,
      GenericRepository<a2Entity> A2
    }
```

Now I realize that we should implement interface both in our BAL and Web layer.
My question is  are there any way  i can mock the services(XService,YService) in our controller to test some behavior (TDD) [for example save change exception occur while saving a entity via'  `_xService.XUnitOfwork.SaveChanges()`'?

Please help.Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mark members (properties, methods) in your concrete class as `virtual`, I think you may be able to just mock those methods / properties individually. (I think the VB equivalent of virtual is Overridable..?)

Moq works by creating a new concrete implementation of something at runtime when your test runs. This is why it works so well with interfaces and abstract classes. But if there is no interface or abstract class, it needs to override a method or property.

**Reply to question author's answer:**

Since you are a self-proclaimed TDD newbie, I just wanted to point out that adding a parameterless constructor to a class just for the sake of making the class testable should not be an acceptable solution.

By giving your GenericRepository class a hard dependency on Entity Framework's DbSet / IDbSet, you are creating a tight coupling between your repository implementation and EF... note the `using System.Data.Entity` line at the top of that file.

Any time you decide to add a constructor dependency, you should seriously consider adding it as an interface or abstract class. If you need access to members of a library which you do not control (like EF's DbContext), follow [Morten's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10878074/304832) and wrap the functionality in your own custom interface.

In the case of DbContext, this class does more than just provide you with a UnitOfWork implementation. It also provides you a way of querying out data and adding / replacing / removing items in your repository:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    int SaveChanges();
}

public interface IQuery
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryable<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
}

public interface ICommand : IQuery
{
    void Add(object entity);
    void Replace(object entity);
    void Remove(object entity);
}
```

You can pretty easily wrap DbContext in these 3 interfaces like so:

```
public class MyCustomDbContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork, ICommand
{
    // DbContext already implements int SaveChanges()

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryable<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return this.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public void Add(object entity)
    {
        this.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
    }

    public void Replace(object entity)
    {
        this.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Remove(object entity)
    {
        this.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
}
```

Note how your interfaces take no dependencies on `System.Data.Entity`. They use primitives and standard .NET types like `object`, `IQueryable<T>`, and `int`. This way, when you give your generic repository dependencies on the interfaces, you can remove the dependency on System.Data.Entity:

```
// using System.Data.Entity; // no need for this dependency any more

public class GenericRepository
{
    private readonly ICommand _entities;
    private readonly IQueryable<TEntity> _queryable;

    public GenericRepository(ICommand entities)
    {
        this._entities = entities;
        this._queryable = entities.GetQueryable<TEntity>();
    }

    //public GenericRepository()
    //{ 
        // no need for a parameterless constructor!
    //}
}
```

...and your GenericRepository is now fully unit testable, since you can easily mock any of these interface methods.

**Final Notes:**

Also, after seeing your answer to your own question, it looks like you have CompanyRepository as a property of your UnitOfWork class. You then inject UnitOfWork as a dependency on your CompanyInformationController. This is backwards. Instead, you should be injecting the CompanyRepository (or its interface) into the controller's constructor. The UnitOfWork pattern has nothing to do with maintaining references for your known repositories. It is about tracking multiple changes made to related items so that they can all be pushed once as a single transaction. EF does this automatically, so as long as AutoFac is providing the same DbContext instance no matter whether your app requests an IQuery, ICommand, or IUnitOfWork implementation, then the only method UnitOfWork should be concerned with is SaveChanges().

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply. The test I was trying to do was successful after spending few hours and changes my previous code.
Changes are follows:
1) Now using UnitofWork in my controller instead of a redundant service.
2) Added a parameter less constructor to the GenericRepository Class.(with out any DBContext!),because it will requied a DBContext as a parameter in Constructor,which can not be substituted by supplying a Mocked DBContext.

**GenericRepository:**
  public class GenericRepository  where TEntity : class
    {

```
    internal DbContext _context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
    public GenericRepository()    //newly added!
    { 

    }
```

...............

**Complete Test**

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Index_Return_OneModel_WhenCalling()
    {
        //arrange

        AutoMapperExtension automapper = new AutoMapperExtension();          
        var moqentities = new Mock<SetupEntities>();                
        List<CompanyInformation> list =new List<CompanyInformation>();
        list.Add(new CompanyInformation{ CompanyName = "a", CompanyAddress = "aa", Id = 1});
        list.Add(new CompanyInformation { CompanyName = "b", CompanyAddress = "b", Id = 2 });                 
        var unitOfWork = new Mock<UnitOfWork>(moqentities.Object);
        unitOfWork.Setup(d => d.CompanyRepository).Returns(new GenericRepository<CompanyInformation>());
        unitOfWork.Setup(d => d.CompanyRepository.GetAll()).Returns(list.AsQueryable());

        var controller = new CompanyInformationController(unitOfWork.Object);          

        //Act
        var result =(ViewResult) controller.Index();
        var model =(CompanyInformationViewModel)  result.ViewData.Model;

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1, model.Id);           

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create an interface for XService. If that is not possible for some reason (if XService is a third party class that doesn't implement an interface),  then consider wrapping the functionality in a wrapperclass that does have an interface.